# Textfield voiceover issue

Tags: iphone, ios, accessibility, voiceover

I am trying to present custom keyboard on `UITextField`.

Every thing works fine but when voice over is on and focus goes on `UITextField`, it says "uitextfield, double tap to edit". Once keyboard is on and again u tap it, it still says same message instead of saying "uitextfield is editing".

This problem persist only when we try to present custom keyboard view.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    field1.inputView=keyBoard;
}

- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField
{
    return TRUE;
}

-(BOOL)textFieldShouldReturn:(UITextField *)textField {
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    return YES;
}
```

As you can see there is not much in the code.Only line which create problem is

```
field1.inputView=keyBoard;
```

If you use Default keyboard then voice-over works as usual.

Comment: Can you show us any of your code?

Comment: there is not much in code, this happens only when we use "inputView" to display custom view.If we comment that line then it's works.So i guess due to that voice-over is somewhere messing up.

Comment: Guys any help will be appreciated..Thanks